# Variable Jump in Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity

I implemented variable jumping in unity for an endless running game.
My question, how can I make the jump frame rate independent?

My algorithm

```
if ( keyDown ){
isJumping = true
ySpeed += jumpStep*Time.deltaTime;
if( ySpeed > maxJumpHeight )
    ySpeed = maxJumpHeight;
   //JUMP OVER
}
// Apply gravity
ySpeed -= ( currentGravity * Time.deltaTime ) ;
// set position
playerSprite.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0,currentPos.y+ySpeed,0);
```

This varies on different devices, What I am trying to do that, whatever the device is, the jump should always be the same on a given time.

What if i do this in FixedUpdate? Will it work fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You **shouldn't** multiply `jumpStep` by `Time.deltaTime`. It should always be the same value, regardless of frame rate.
- You **should** multiply `currentGravity` by `Time.deltatime`.
- In the last part, you should do `currentPos.y + ySpeed * Time.deltaTime`, When you use speed to compute movement, you need to multiply speed by time.

That is because jumping is an impulse and gravity a force. Impulses happen in an infinitely small time frame. Forces act over time.

Comment: If the jumpStep is same on every frame,the jump will take more time to reach MAXIMUM on 30FPS and less on 60FPS.
How can I make sure then it should always jump at max 100 in 2 seconds?

Comment: You should have one piece of code that decides if the player is on the ground and hit the jump key. You cannot jump whilst in mid-air. Then, whenever the character can jump and the players hits the jump button, you should set ySpeed to the jump movement speed. After that, each frame, adjust the y-position and the speed and it should work fine. The jump should end when gravity takes the character back to the ground. It will always take `initial_jump_speed` / `current_gravity` time. So it should work fine even if you set the initial jump speed to a constant value.

Comment: by "adjust the yPosition and speed" you mean that I should calculate the ySpeed based on the current delta time?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Just one thing.. It will take  `initial_jump_speed` / `current_gravity` for the jump speed to reach zero and the character will stop gaining height and begins to fall.

Comment: **"Impulses happen in an infinitely small time frame. Forces act over time."** best explanation I've read about this so far.